# Ideal axle diameter function derivation

Tags: structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, stresses, mathematics

I am interested in the reference of and any papers that discuss the derivation of the "ideal axle".

By an ideal axle I mean an axle that has the same strength along all its cross sections.

I will examine only the bending stresses in the following.

So let's start from the main equation that is used for bending moments:

$$\sigma_f=\frac{M_y}{W}\leq\sigma_{allowed}$$

where

$$W=\frac{\pi d^3}{64}\approx0.1d^3$$

So we get

$$\sigma_{allowed}=\sigma_f=\frac{M_y}{W}=\frac{M_f}{0.1d^3}=\frac{10\cdot M_f}{d^3}$$

Now if we want to get the "ideal" diameter we would say that:

$$d=\sqrt[3]{\frac{10\cdot M_f}{\sigma_{allowed}}}\tag1$$

From this we want to get $d$ as a function of $x$ so:

$$d(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{10\cdot F_A \cdot x_1}{\sigma_{allowed}}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{10\cdot F_A }{\sigma_{allowed}}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{x_1}=k_1\sqrt[3]{x_1}.$$

So we see that it would be a polynomial of the third order, and if we were to rotate it around the $x$ axis we would get a rotational paraboloid like in the picture.

I can not find any references on the net and I would really appreciate if you could share some and/or suggest some reading materials. Who was the first scientist to determine it this way?

[image]

Comment: Mathematicians have been mucking about with structural analysis since the 18th century (if not before) and have left the subject with a residue of hard core maths which has been torturing engineering students ever since. As such I suggest you look at Euler and his mates, not scientists. Your initial equation is rendered incorrectly, so I didn't bother checking the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: What is ideal for my machine may not be ideal for yours -- particularly if you start thinking about production cost.  If you have some closed-form way of expressing what is ideal, or some closed-form cost function, then there are plenty of ways to find solutions to the resulting optimization problem.